# Can't build C program "bcasync2"

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

This question might go unanswered; because it deals with a certain brand of software from Data Device Corporation (DDC).

I’m trying to run a C program in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express; and I’m getting errors.

DDC provided some software in a folder called:  “BU-69092S0_3_2_15”.

In that folder there was a “setup” application which I ran.  The setup applicaton created a folder called DDC.

Inside the DDC folder was another folder called “aceXtremeSDKv3215”.  In this folder there is a “Samples” folder which has the samples available to run.

I’m unable to run any of these samples in Visual Studios.  I was initially trying to run the “bcasync2” solution first but could not get it to work.  I then began to try other samples but all have the same error.

What happens:

I start Visual Studios, and then I go to Open->Project/Solution.

Then I navigate to a sample (such as bcasync2) and I click Open.

I get a warning which reads:  `C:\DDC\aceXtremeSDKv3215\Samples\bcasync2\BCAsync2.vcxproj : warning  : Platform 'x64' referenced in the project file 'S_BcAsync2' cannot be found. Please make sure you have it installed under '%VCTargetsPath%\Platforms\x64'.`
(But it’s only a warning so I move on.)

Then I click on the green arrow.

I’m asked if I want to build this project.  I click on Yes.

I get build errors.  The first line reads:  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets(1422,5): warning : The referenced project '..\..\emacepl.vcxproj' does not exist.`

After this line I get many LNK2019 errors:

```
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceGetLibVersion@0 referenced in function _PrintHeader
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceErrorStr@12 referenced in function _PrintOutError
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceGetBSWErrString@8 referenced in function _DisplayDecodedMsg
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceCmdWordParse@20 referenced in function _DisplayDecodedMsg
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceGetMsgTypeString@4 referenced in function _DisplayDecodedMsg
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceBCStop@4 referenced in function _GetBCMsgsFromID
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceBCGetMsgFromIDDecoded@16 referenced in function _GetBCMsgsFromID
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceBCAsyncMsgCreateBCtoRT@36 referenced in function _GetBCMsgsFromID
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceBCSendAsyncMsgHP@12 referenced in function _GetBCMsgsFromID
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceBCStart@12 referenced in function _GetBCMsgsFromID
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceFree@4 referenced in function _main
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceBCAsyncMsgCreateRTtoBC@36 referenced in function _main
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceBCFrameCreate@28 referenced in function _main
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceBCOpCodeCreate@28 referenced in function _main
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceBCMsgCreateBCtoRT@32 referenced in function _main
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceBCDataBlkCreate@20 referenced in function _main
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceBCConfigure@8 referenced in function _main
1>bcasync2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aceInitialize@24 referenced in function _main
1>Win32\Release\bcasync2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 18 unresolved externals
```

I believe that those symbols are probably supposed to be found in the “emacepl.vcxproj” file that it cannot find.  (I don't know for sure.)

But "emacepl.vcxpro" is nowhere to be found in the DDC folder that was created after I clicked on the “setup” application in “BU-69092S0_3_2_15”.

Has anyone out there run into this issue when working with this software?  Or does anyone see something I may be doing wrong  with Visual Studios.  Thanks so much!

Comment: to start, 'warnings' are when the compiler (or linker) finds something that it thinks is wrong, but which does not violate the C standard being used.   Warnings need to be fixed.  In this case, it is indicating that some critical resource is not available.

Comment: There is some indication that the project file is NOT for a visual studio project file.  Suggest building a new project (probably in the same directory)

Comment: Would I build a new project and then add that project in somehow?

Comment: at <http://www.ddc-web.com/Products/172/Default.aspx> are all the documents related to the BU-69092 project.  Have read those documents?  within the documents are the free help lines.  suggest you use those help lines:   US Toll Free Technical Support:
1-800-DDC-5757, ext. 7771
Outside of the US Technical Support:
1-631-567-5600, ext. 7771

Comment: did you read this in the documentation: "The “Include” directory contains the header files needed for compiling an application
written for the AceXtreme SDK.  When creating an application the user will have to
configure his compiler to include the path to this folder in order to correctly compile an
executable."

Comment: Sorry, that link is broken.  I have skimmed through the documents though, for something relating to running the samples in Visual Studios, but have found nothing.  I do have a user account, and I have requested help; though I have had no reply quite yet.

Comment: suggest using the supplied phone numbers for getting help.  The only way to access to document/source/etc directorys is via the DDC login screen, then select the bd-... project.

Comment: Here is what the documentation says about needed libraries: "The “Lib” directory contains the emacepl.lib file, which is needed to compile an
application written against the AceXtreme SDK. Also included in this directory is a
second copy the emacepl.dll which is also installed in C:\Windows\System32. The file
emacepls.lib is a statically built copy of the emacepl.lib file"

Comment: Thanks the note about configuring the compiler.  I did left click on the project, and then I went to Properties->C/C++->General.  I made sure the Include directory was listed in “Additional Include Directories”.  All the header files from the Include folder show up under the External Dependencies folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the problem description, it seems the product was not properly installed.

The following is the installation instructions for Linux.

When downloading the product version for windows, a similar file is available.

The contents of the Linux 'install.txt' file.

```
-------------
Installation
-------------
1. Login as normal unprivileged user and create a working 
   directory for this package:
   (In this example, assume UID is 'devel' & GID is 'users')
        mkdir ~/DDC1553[S,D]1_x_y_z_b

2. Change to that directory:
        cd ~/DDC1553[S,D]1_x_y_z_b

3. Copy the distribution archive to the working directory:
        cp <path_to_archive>/BU69092[S,D]1_x_y_z_b.tgz .

4. Enter 'superuser' mode:
        su

5. Extract the distribution archive:
        tar -xzpPf BU69092[S,D]1_x_y_z_b.tgz

6. Change the ownership of all distribution files 
   in the user's home directory to normal user:
        chown -R devel.users *

7. Install the Run-time library binaries using the supplied 
   script 'install-emacepl.sh' in the 'tools' directory:
        cd tools
        ./install-emacepl.sh
        cd ..

8. Install the Ace support library binaries (optional) using 
   the supplied script 'install-acetoemace.sh' in the 'tools' 
   directory:
        cd tools
        ./install-acetoemace.sh
        cd ..

9. Install the TstSim support library binaries (optional) using 
   the supplied script 'install-tstsim.sh' in the 'tools' 
   directory:
        cd tools
        ./install-tstsim.sh
        cd ..

10. Exit 'superuser' mode:
        exit

---------------
Uninstallation
---------------
1. List all files installed onto the system:

   tar -tzvf BU69092[S,D]1_x_y_z_b.tgz

2. Delete all listed files, along with the driver objects written 
   to the kernel modules library tree, and/or the DDC system 
   directory during the driver build stages.

3. Remove the software suite from the system

--------------------
Further Information
--------------------
Refer to the ~/DDC1553[S,D]1_x_y_z_b/readme.txt file for further 
guidance pertaining to the installation and utilization of this 
software suite.
```

Notice the directions about installing the library.
From the linker messages, it seems either the library was not installed
or visual C++ was not configured to search the library.

Comment: Earlier you wrote about building a new project.  A co-worker of mine did a New->Project From Existing Code... and that got rid of those errors I was seeing.  Thanks again for all your help.  A new project was the answer.